# Caesar Cipher-Why is it when I enter a key value of for eg 5, the character encryption shifts by 11?

Tags: c#, caesar-cipher

Why is it when I enter a key value of 5 for eg, the character shifts by 11 not 5?

```cs
string ciphertext = "";
Console.WriteLine("Enter ur text ");
string plaintext = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter ur key ");
int key = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

foreach(char number in plaintext)
{
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(number);
    if(value + key > 90)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(char.ConvertFromUtf32(value + key - 26));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(char.ConvertFromUtf32(value + key));
    }
}
```

I am expecting a shift of characters according to the key value

Comment: What about case? If you enter `'a'` (decimal 97) and subtract 26, you get `'G'`.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt32(number)` will try to interpret the the character as decimal digit. E.g., `Convert.ToInt32('4') => 4`. This is not what you want. To get its character code you can simply cast to `int`. E.g. `(int)'A' => 65`.

You can treat characters as numbers and add the key directly and cast the `int` result back to `char`.

```cs
Console.Write("Enter ur text: ");
string plaintext = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter ur key: ");
int key = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

foreach (char character in plaintext) {
    int shiftedCharCode = character + key;
    if (shiftedCharCode > 'z' || (shiftedCharCode > 'Z' && shiftedCharCode < 'a')) {
        shiftedCharCode -= 26;
    }
    Console.WriteLine((char)shiftedCharCode);
}
```